# Laravel: Calling a common function for multiple Models from anywhere in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I am working on a Laravel 5.4 app. In that I have a booking in which we add `Tours, Flights, Hotels` which are separate section along with their separate Model / Controller / Views with operations of CURD. `Tours, Flights, Hotels` stores data in separate tables along with price of that item.

I have in total 4 tables `Bookings, Tours, Flights, Hotels`. Bookings have `booking_id` which related further to `Tours, Flights, Hotels` and these all can have multiple entries against a booking. I can have 2 hotels, or 4 tours against a `booking_id`.

Now, I have a billing section where I need to show all the entries with their no of items and price and a sub total of all items as total booking price.

I need a function which I can call from anywhere in the system and can show the booking total and if needed itemized list too.

Should I create a **new Model/Controller** for that purpose or a **Trait** maybe? Not able to think how should I do this in Laravel.

Please check and advise some solution/concept for this and I will try to implement it.

Comment: I think you can create a trait for that

Comment: ok, so when I use trait I will call its method like `static::getBookingSubTotal()` ? without creating an instance etc.?

Comment: I think you can call it without `static`, it was injected right :)

Answer (score 0):

Directory:
    /app/Http/Helpers

- Add some a `Helper` class there with `namespace`: `App\Http\Helpers`.
- Put all your methods in there.
- You can now call them from anywhere as long as you import the namespace `App\Http\Helpers`.
- If to don't want to typehint and make laravel resolve these dependencies, you can just have `static` methods, then you won't need to instantiate anything saving you some time.

Comment: ok, so what is better method a Trait or Helper? And if I use the trait, that same things as Helper or different? Please advise!